# MySQL COUNT() GROUP BY - How to turn none-grouped columns into arrays or make priorities?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

My first question here.

I have this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(wishid) AS occurances FROM wishes GROUP BY productid HAVING status = 0 ORDER BY occurances DESC LIMIT 5
```

The table also has a "userid" column which specifies which user added the wish.

I want to create a Top-5 list of products that are wished the most, and i need to know which of the products the current user has wished, in order to highlight these.

How can i do this? I would love if the `$row['userid']` would become an array of the `userid-column-values` after grouping, but it seems that it is just one of the values (propably the first one before grouping.). Then i could do `in_array($userid, $row['userid'])` for each row.

Alternatively, if i could set priorities for the other columns before grouping, that would be fine. E.g.:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(wishid) AS occurances FROM wishes GROUP BY productid **(if column 'userid' is equal to $userid, the 'userid'-value of the grouped rows should be $userid, else whatever)** HAVING status = 0 ORDER BY occurances DESC LIMIT 5
```

I hope you can help! Maybe i need something totally different?

(BTW: The query works, but lacks the functionality stated above.)

Answer (score 0):

Try `GROUP_CONCAT` on the userid field.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more column based on the MAX( IF() ) test.  If the user of the record being counted is that of the user in question, set to 1, otherwise, leave it as zero.  Now, you have a flag on the record if the person wished for it or not.

```
SELECT
      *, 
      COUNT(wishid) AS occurances,
      MAX( IF( userID = TheUserIDToCompareAgainst, 1, 0 )) as WishByCurrentPersonFlag
   from 
      wishes 
   GROUP BY 
      productid 
   HAVING 
      status = 0 
   ORDER BY 
      occurances DESC
   LIMIT 5
```